# Any way to communicate with WebView in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

Is it possible to interact with a webview in android trough my native android code?

I develop can bus driver for android and I like to send my can bus data to a html 5 app in a webview without sending them over internet to a webservice. or is it possible to call funktions via the html 5 app in my native android app?

Do you know a good solution for that scenario?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check out [`addJavascriptInterface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 15):

Here is a good example how to call javascript running inside the WebView:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html

Comment: thank you :) this is really nice!! i'm really happy there is a way for that :)