# Android Webview detect cookie in a webpage where the content is dynamically loaded using div

Tags: android, html, cookies, android-webview

I'm loading a website in *Android* `WebView` in which each page is loaded dynamically by changing content of div,I have to check for cookies frequently whenever next page is loaded(i.e,whenever the content of div is changed) and then redirect to `Activity` accordingly.

I'm able to detect cookies the very first time the page is loaded,but since only the div is changing and not the `url`,I'm not able to detect or not able to check cookies second time.

Any idea of how to deal with this?

Any help on this is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The specific design you're describing is pretty hard to deal with.

If you are able to control the content of the page I would suggest having the JavaScript that changes the div contents also communicate back the new state to the app (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341159/any-way-to-communicate-with-webview-in-android) on how to do this).

If you are unable to control the content you could use `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest` to "monitor" the requests made by the page but this includes all the requests made by the WebView so it might be hard to filter out just the ones made by the changing div.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion,I'll try with that and is it possible to do with Threads to check with Cookies frequently?

Comment: @Vijay - "it possible to do with Threads to check with Cookies" - sorry, I don't understand that bit. If you're trying to check if there is an auth cookie (using CookieManager APIs) using a separate thread then that should be fine.